# Create a polygon in SVG from a group of elements in JS

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG with groups of elements (which are all a uniform shape but the group shape can vary. Obviously putting an outline on the group will give me a rectangle shape. What I am trying to achieve is a polygon that outlines the group giving a rough trace of the items:

http://codepen.io/wroughtec/pen/OXvRrq

(below is an example with circles although have also included a path example as that is what I am actually being given)

```
<h2>No Outline</h2>
<svg viewbox="0 0 1000 200">
  <g>
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="20" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="80" cy="50" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="110" cy="50" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="140" cy="50" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="80" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="110" cy="80" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="140" cy="80" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="170" cy="80" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="80" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="170" cy="110" r="10" fill="grey" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="110" r="10" fill="grey" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I need to be able to do this automatically in JS but getting the x and y of the circles gives me the center point so my manual one I have had to cheat to expand  to the outer shape of the circles and remove unnecessary points (i.e. points on the same line or in the middle).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the points.

[D3.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Hull-Geom.md) implements this, and a good example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4341699). (The code is rather lengthy, so I won't reproduce it here; the main function of interest is `d3.geom.hull`)

Note that D3.js v4 was just recently released, and almost all code online (including what I linked) is written for v3. There are significant changes between the two, but v4 still has a [convex hull function](https://github.com/d3/d3-polygon/blob/master/README.md#polygonHull).